# LaTeX \begin{align} twice align

Tags: equations, align

I have a code with an equation:

```
\begin{align*}
&min(\norm{[\hat{w}(k)-\hat{y}(k)-&M^P \Delta \hat{u}^P (k)]-M \Delta \hat{u}(k)}_\psi^2 +\norm{\Delta \hat{u}(k)}_\Lambda^2)\\
&\text{\textit{za podmínek}} &-\Delta U_{max} \leq \Delta\hat{u}(k) \leq \Delta U_{max}\\
&&U_{min}\leq U(k-1)+J \Delta \hat{u}(k)\leq U_{max}\\
&&Y_{min} \leq \hat{y}^0 (k)+M\Delta \hat{u}(k) \leq Y_{max}
\end{align*}
```

The output is

[image: badAlign]

But I need the following output:[image]

First blue line first align, second blue line second align. Both align left.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I doubt you can get that output without error, as `\norm` cannot span multiple cells in your `align`ment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the `alignat*` environment. Here are two layouts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & \min\bigl(\norm{[\hat{w}(k)-\hat{y}(k)-{} & & M^P Δ\hat{u}^P (k)]-M Δ\hat{u}(k)}_\psi² +\norm{Δ\hat{u}(k)}_\Lambda²\bigr) \\
    & \textit{za podmínek} & &\mathllap{-}ΔU_{\max} \leq Δ\hat{u}(k) \leq ΔU_{\max} \\
    & & & U_{\min}\leq U(k-1)+J Δ\hat{u}(k)\leq U_{\max} \\
    & & & Y_{\min} \leq \hat{y}⁰ (k)+MΔ\hat{u}(k) \leq Y_{\max}
\end{alignat*}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    & \min\bigl(\norm{[\hat{w}(k)-\hat{y}(k)& &-M^P Δ\hat{u}^P (k)]-M Δ\hat{u}(k)}_\psi² +\norm{Δ\hat{u}(k)}_\Lambda²\bigr) \\
    & \textit{za podmínek} & & \begin{array}[t]{|@{\quad}l}
    \mathllap{-}ΔU_{\max} \leq Δ\hat{u}(k) \leq ΔU_{\max} \\
    U_{\min}\leq U(k-1)+J Δ\hat{u}(k)\leq U_{\max} \\
     Y_{\min} \leq \hat{y}⁰ (k)+MΔ\hat{u}(k) \leq Y_{\max}
    \end{array}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd probably use `& & - M` in line 1, and `{-}\Delta` in line 2 of your `alignat*`.

Comment: @Werner: I wondered, precisely. And an `\hphantom{-}` for the last two lines?

Comment: Sure... Question remains unclear though.

Comment: @Werner: Finally, no: the spacings around $-$ are not the same in both lines.

Comment: @Bernard -- the spacings for the two `$-$` should *not* be the same; the one before the delta is unary and the other is binary.  (or is that what you really meant by your last comment?)

Comment: @barbara beeton: That's what I said in my last post – and that's indeed the result.

Comment: @Bernard -- oh, i didn't mean to question the result -- it is correct.  i wasn't sure that i didn't misunderstand the explanation.  thank you for confirming.

Comment: Thanks. Its working. I have a question. Why do you use three symbols "&"? Why can't i use only two "&"?

Comment: This is the normal syntax: after an alignment point, marked with `&`, the next alignment group is introduced by another `&`, and inside that group, the alignment point is marked with a third `&`. So, if you want *n*  alignment points, you need *2n – 1* `&`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with `array` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz,varwidth,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert

    \begin{document}
\[\renewcommand\arraycolsep{1pt}
    \begin{array}{lcl}
min(\norm{[\hat{w}(k)-\hat{y}(k)
    & - & M^P \Delta \hat{u}^P (k)] - M 
            \Delta\hat{u}(k)}_\psi^2 + 
            \norm{\Delta \hat{u}(k)}_\Lambda^2)                 \\
\text{\textit{za podmínek}} 
    & - & \Delta U_{max} \leq \Delta\hat{u}(k)\leq \Delta U_{max}  \\
    &   & U_{min}\leq U(k-1)+J \Delta \hat{u}(k)\leq U_{max}        \\
    &   & Y_{min} \leq \hat{y}^0 (k)+M\Delta \hat{u}(k) \leq Y_{max}
\end{array}\]
    \end{document}
```

[image]